# How can I solve for the matrix coefficients in this Poisson image editing implementation?

Tags: image-processing

[This article](http://www.ctralie.com/Teaching/PoissonImageEditing/) explains how we can blend images using Poisson image editing. In this implementation, we get the Poisson equation from which we form a system of linear equations Ax=B.

I'm having a hard time in understanding what the coefficients would be in matrix A and B. I believe matrix B is the gradient of the image which we are pasting over another image.

Once I know what A and B are, I can write a program to solve the equations. How can I find what A and B would be?

Comment: Have a look at this [DSP question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/implementing-discrete-poisson-equation-wtih-neumann-boundary-condition/1655#1655)

Comment: I finally find out what A and B would be. A is discrete laplacian matrix which is a sparse matrix and B is obtained by moving the constant terms of equations to right hand side and adding source image gradient to it. Thus we have an equation Ax=B. I came across csparse and taucs C-libraries for solving this equation. However, when I try to add these libraries in my project, I get errors. Just worndering What library can I use to sovlve this equation in ios.